# How to add a checkout button to header but not in the top links

Tags: checkout, cart

how do i add in a checkout button into the header, but not within the top links?

I havent tried anything yet because i dont know where to start, hence why i am asking for your help.

All i need is a simple link that goes to checkout or my cart.

Thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your theme's `header.phtml` file to include a link to the checkout by doing the following:

1. Open `app/design/frontend/[theme-parent]/[theme-child]/template/page/html/header.phtml`
2. Insert `<a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/url')->getCheckoutUrl(); ?>">Checkout</a>` where you want the link to appear.

Comment: Perfect that A link you provided was exactly what i was looking for!